# Systemd user service exec command not in path

Tags: systemd, nixos

In my NixOS `configuration.nix`, I created the following service :

```
systemd.user.services.xcape-daemon = {
  description = "Xcape Daemon";
  after=[ "graphical.target" ];

  serviceConfig = {
    Type = "forking";
    ExecStart = ''${pkgs.xcape} -e "Hyper-L=Tab;Hyper_R=less"'';
    # ExecStop = "pkill xcape"; #pkill not found in path
    Restart = "on-failure";
  };

  wantedBy = [ "default.target" ];
};

systemd.user.services.xcape-daemon.enable = true;
```

However, I get the following error when checking the status of the service:

```
Executable "xcape" not found in path "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin"
```

Problem is that this is not my actual $PATH.

My $PATH is : `/home/user/bin /run/wrappers/bin /home/user/.nix-profile/bin /etc/profiles/per-user/user/bin /nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin /run/current-system/sw/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually expected, as systemd uses a *fixed* value for `$PATH` determined at compilation time (to determine whether you're on a split-usr distro or not).

Quote from the [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) man page:

> ```
>  $PATH
>        Colon-separated list of directories to use when launching executables.  systemd uses a fixed value of "/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin" in the system manager. When compiled for systems with "unmerged
>        /usr" (/bin is not a symlink to /usr/bin), ":/sbin:/bin" is appended. In case of the the user manager, each bin/ and sbin/ pair is switched, so that programs from /usr/bin have higher priority than programs from /usr/sbin,
>        etc. It is recommended to not rely on this in any way, and have only one program with a given name in $PATH.
> ```

You have several options how to solve this:

1. Use a full path to the `xcape` binary: `ExecStart=/full/path/to/bin/xcape -e ...`
2. Define your own `$PATH` by using either:

   a. `Environment="PATH=/bin:/sbin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:..."`

   b. `EnvironmentFile=/etc/myservice/myenvfile` where `/etc/myservice/myenvfile` contains definitions of environment variables (see [systemd.exec(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html) for documentation to both directives)